# Python- Get Stock Information for a company for a range of dates

Tags: javascript, python, json, finance

Trying to get more than just the stock information at the current time period, and I can't figure out if Google Finance allows for retrieving information for more than just one date.  For example, if I wanted to find out the Google Stock value over the last 30 days and return that data as a list... how would I go about doing this?

Using the code below only gets me a single value:

```
class GoogleFinanceAPI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.prefix = "http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q="

    def get(self,symbol,exchange):
        url = self.prefix+"%s:%s"%(exchange,symbol)
        u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        content = u.read()

        obj = json.loads(content[3:])
        return obj[0]


c = GoogleFinanceAPI()
quote = c.get("MSFT","NASDAQ")
print quote
```

Comment: What does their documentation say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a recipe to get a historical values from Google Finance:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576495-get-a-stock-historical-value-from-google-finance/

It looks like it returns the data in .csv format.

Edit: Here is your script modified to get the .csv. It works for me.

```
import urllib2
import csv

class GoogleFinanceAPI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = "http://finance.google.com/finance/historical?client=ig&q={0}:{1}&output=csv"
    def get(self,symbol,exchange):
        page = urllib2.urlopen(self.url.format(exchange,symbol))
        content = page.readlines()
        page.close()
        reader = csv.reader(content)
        for row in reader:
            print row

c = GoogleFinanceAPI()
c.get("MSFT","NASDAQ")
```

Comment: Tried to get this to work many times-- pretty sure Google changed its interface since it was made so that the screenscraping technique no longer works

Comment: http://www.google.com/finance/historical?client=ig&q=MSFT:NASDAQ&output=csv works fine for me.

Comment: Amazing!  I was trying to get CSV reader to read the content in the correct way, but never could.  For future users of this script, I had to add "urlopen(self.url.format...)" for it to work.

Comment: Whoops, missed that. I removed the use of `prefix` after I tested. Fixed. `csv.reader` takes a sequence of strings, so if you `read()` it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to go forward is use the [API](http://code.google.com/apis/finance/docs/2.0/reference.html#Parameters)'s provided by Google. Specifically look for returns parameter where you specify how long you want.

Instead, if you want to do it via Python, find out query pattern as where the date entry goes and substitute it in the URL and do a GET, parse the result and include it in your result list.